# How to write own LocationService for Android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I would like to implement my own location service. It will be based on triangulation of the wifi signal strengths of the nearby access points.

I know the algorithm to determine my location, but I don't know how to integrate it in my code so that I can simply add a LocationListener to my service.

```
MyWifiLocationService wifiLocationService = new MyWifiLocationService();
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //has to be called, if there is a new location (via wifi triangulation)
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};
wifiLocationService.setLocationListener(locationListener);
```

How could I write the MyWifiLocationService class? Does anybody know a tutorial for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a service and that can be controlled by AlarmManager.In this service, implement your algorithm for fetching location.